# Two Trigger of same type on same table which will get executed first?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a very basic doubt.
Suppose we heve two after insert trigger TR1 and TR2 on table 1.
One trigger updates same Table 1 and second trigger Call procedure ..
I need TR1 to execute before TR2..
How this can be achieved..
Thanks

Comment: The question is, why would anybody have two triggers of the same type on the one table?  Obviously lots of people do, because Oracle has introduced the functionality Tony discusses, but it's just - um - weird.

Comment: @APC: maybe you might want two triggers of the same type, but with different conditions on them? Obviously this could still be done with IF statements within one trigger, but I think there may be performance benefits to using conditionals.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - That sounds plausible.  I avoid using triggers for all but the simplest of logic, which rarely leads to the need for conditionals.  But I know other people love triggers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Oracle 11G you can use the PRECEDES or FOLLOWS clauses e.g.

```
create trigger TR2
after insert on table1
for each row
follows TR1 -------------------------------------------------<<
begin
 ...
end;
```

Prior to 11G the order if firing was indeterminate; the only way to ensure correct execution was to combine the 2 triggers into 1.